# PyTorch wheel not supported on this platform error while deploying application

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, deployment, pytorch

I am trying to deploy my pytorch application on [zeet](https://zeet.co) and my requirments.txt file contains this-

```
https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.3.1%2Bcpu-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
pickle-mixin
flask
simpletransformers
selenium
gunicorn
cloudpickle
```

When I try to build my application, I get the following error :

```py
ERROR: torch-1.3.1+cpu-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
Build failed
```

I tried using multiple different versions of the wheel, but none to be working, I even tried the windows build but that isnt working too and I tried all the solutions I could find online but none seem to be working.

EDIT : My build command is `pip install -r requirements.txt` and my python version is `python 3.8`

Any Help Would Be Appreciated!!

Comment: can you [edit] your question to post the welcome/version prompt of python when you're running it interactively? also how are you calling the install with pip?

Comment: okay done, I added the python version  I'm using and the build command for the application

Comment: you can't use a wheel that's been explicitly tagged as 3.6 on a 3.8 version. You didn't specify the architecture of your version (32 or 64 bit) that's why I wanted you to paste the copyright/version message not just the version

Answer (score 0):

In your requirements, you have a wheel dedicated for python 3.6 but you are using python 3.8 -  `cp36-cp36m` part of the name `torch-1.3.1%2Bcpu-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl`, to be exact. You should provide only version of `torch` in your `requirements.txt` (recommended) and make sure that you are using the same version of Python when developing and deploying.

Name of the wheel is the convention that is described [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/#file-name-convention). It encapsulates where the wheel can be used.